# sql запрос с несколькими join

Tags: sql, join

Есть таблички:

```
cosmonauts: 
  id, 
  full_name(text), 
  birthdate(datetime), 
  country_id, 
  can_be_pilot(true/false), 
  rank(number)

tasks: 
  id, 
  title(text), 
  description(text), 
  deadline(datetime)

cosmonauts_schedule: 
  id, 
  cosmonaut_id, 
  task_id, 
  starts_at(datetime)

visits_to_shops: 
  id, 
  shop_id, 
  cosmonaut_id, 
  visit_date(datetime) 

shops: 
  id, 
  name(text), 
  distance(number)

liquids: 
  id, 
  title(text)

liquids_supply: 
  id, 
  shop_id, 
  supplier_id, 
  liquid_id, 
  supply_date(datetime), 
  amount(number), 
  is_on_sale_now(true/false)
```

Нужно ​ ​выбрать ​ ​того, ​ ​кто ​ ​умеет​ ​пилотировать ​ ​корабль, ​ ​и ​ ​у​ ​кого ​ ​есть ​ ​полностью​ ​свободный ​ ​от​ ​задач день в течении недели с сегодняшнего дня.
Скидку​ ​шоп ​ ​дает​ ​только ​ ​тем, ​ ​кто ​ ​в ​ ​нем ​ ​уже ​ ​бывал. ​ ​Вам ​ ​очень ​ ​нужно ​ ​сэкономить. ​ ​Топливо ​ ​тоже стоит​ ​денег, ​так ​ ​что ​ ​вам ​ ​выгодно ​ ​найти ​ ​ближайший ​ ​шоп. И еще нужно наличие в шопе 1000 ​ ​бутылок жидкости ​ ​«Deep ​ ​space».

Сам запрос с пропущенными кусками:

```
select possible_flights.date, 
    possible_flights.cosmonaut_id,
    possible_shops.shop_id,
    c.full_name, s.name
from (
    select date, cosmonaut_id
    from /*
    ... Your code here ...
    */
    group by 1, 2
) as possible_flights

join cosmonauts c on c.id = possible_flights.cosmonaut_id 
join visits_to_shops vs on vs.cosmonaut_id = c.id 
join shops s on s.id = vs.shop_id

join ( 
    select s.id as shop_id, s.distance
    from shops s 
    join liquids_supply ls on ls.shop_id = s.id 
    join liquids l on l.id = ls.liquid_id 
    where /*
    ... Your code here ...
    */
) possible_shops on possible_shops.shop_id = s.id 

group by 1, 2, 3
order by possible_shops.distance, possible_flights.date
limit 10
;
```

Comment: и чего с ним?..

Comment: @teran все голову сломал в решении задачи, есть запрос, в котором нужно заполнить пропущенные места, я начал разбирать по частям пока не могу полностью все написать